# Mismatching screenshot display types between App Store Connect website and API

Tags: app-store-connect, app-store-connect-api

When I open an iOS app in the App Store Connect website and disclose the Apple Watch section, it reads `Apple Watch Ultra, Series 8, 6, 3`, but the documentation for the [API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/screenshotdisplaytype) lists different versions:

```
APP_WATCH_ULTRA
APP_WATCH_SERIES_7
APP_WATCH_SERIES_4
APP_WATCH_SERIES_3
```

So the Watch Series don't seem to match.

There is a similar issue with iPad Pro. The website reads  `iPad Pro (6th Gen) 12.9" Display` and `iPad Pro (2nd Gen) 12.9" Display`, but the API reads

```
APP_IPAD_PRO_3GEN_129
APP_IPAD_PRO_129
```

So again the Gen values don't seem to match.

How should I interpret these values?